# Probabilistic Combinatorial problem - consecutive runs of $1$s in a string of $0$s and $1$s

Tags: real-analysis, probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, solution-verification

Let $n$ values $0$ or $1$ be arranged around a circle, and for a given $k$ consider the number of runs of $k$ consecutive $1$s. Suppose the $n$ values are independent and each of them is equal to $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$. Let $X$ be the number of runs of $k$ consecutive $1$s. Assume that $k\le n/2$.

(a) Find $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\textrm{Var}(X)$ as functions of $n,k$ and $p$.

(b) Now suppose $p=1/2$ and that $k$ depends on $n$. Define $k=\log_2(n)+\omega(n)$. Show that if $\omega(n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ then $\mathbb{P}(X=0)\to 1$ and if $\omega(n)\to -\infty$ as $n\to \infty$ then $\mathbb{P}(X=0)\to 0$ and also that $$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{X}{\mathbb{E}[X]}-1\right|\ge\varepsilon\right)\to 0,$$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Idea: in a stretch of any $k$ numbers on the circle, the probability they are all $1$s is $p^k$. The number of stretches of $k$ numbers on the circle of $n$ numbers is $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$. So the expected number of runs of $k$ consecutive runs of $1$s is \begin{equation}\mathbb{E}[X]=p^k\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor.\end{equation}
For the variance, I assume we would do something similar, noting that $\textrm{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$, but I am not sure how to compute $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ in this case. As for (b), this looks a lot like Chebyshev's inequality, and I believe a trivial application of it gives the result.

Comment: There's always some ambiguity when speaking of runs of a fixed length.  If your sequence was $01110$, how many runs of length $2$ would you say it had?

Comment: The number of stretches of length $k$ is $n,$ not $\lfloor n/k\rfloor.$ So $E(X)=np^k.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ah yes I see! Any ideas how to find the variance?

Comment: @lulu I'm not quite sure what you mean - I would say two runs of length $2$?

Comment: It's your question.  Some people would say there were none.  That there was one run of length $3$ and no runs of any other length.  The issue, of course, is whether overlaps are allowed.  If you are saying that there are, then linearity works easily for the expectation and you can compute $E[X^2]$ the same way, though it is somewhat more work.

Comment: Don't use tagged comments to ask people to answer your question. You've already asked your question. If I wanted and was able to answer it, I would have done so. Tagging me asking me to finish answering the question is rude. @alidixon222

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry! I didn't mean to offend.

Comment: @lulu let's allow overlaps; in this case, I think we can use the following fact: Let $X=I_1+\cdots+I_k$ where each $I_i$ is the indicator function of some event $A_i$. Then $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^k\mathbb{P}(A_i\cap A_j)$. It isn't immediately obvious how to use this though

Comment: No reason to introduce some events $A_i$, we know what event each indicator variable is attached to.  What is $X^2$ in terms of the indicator variables?  What is $I_j^2$?  What can you say about $I_j\times I_k$?

Comment: @lulu I would say the indicator event $I_i$ is the event that there is a string of $i$ ones, but that would be wrong:(

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Let $Y_i = 1$ if there is a run of $k$ ones starting at position $i$ ($i=1, 2 \cdots n$), $Y_i=0$ otherwhise.

Then $X = \sum_i Y_i$. This should give you $E[X]$ directly.

For the variance, compute $E[X^2]$ (this is a little more convolved, but not much).

Added:

$$\begin{align}E[X^2] &= E[ (\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)^2 ]\\
&= E [\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n Y_i Y_j ] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n E[Y_i Y_j ] \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n P(Y_i=1 \cap Y_j=1) \\
&=n \sum_{j=1}^n P(Y_1=1 \cap Y_j=1) \\
&=n [ a_k + 2 a_{k+1} + 2 a_{k+2}  \cdots 2 a_{2k-1} + (n- 2k-1)a_k^2 ]
\end{align}$$

where $a_j$ is the probability of having a run of $j$ ones starting at position $1$. Can you go on from here?

Comment: So $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[\sum_iY_i]=np^k$; the probability of a run of $k$ ones at any of the positions is $p^k$, and there are $n$ of them (as in a comment). As for computing $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$, I am not quite sure